# z3: What might be the reason for timeout

Tags: z3

What might be the reason for timeout for the following program in z3.

http://rise4fun.com/Z3/pbEOw

```
(declare-const a Int)
(declare-const a2 Int)
(declare-const b Int)
(assert (> b 0))
(assert (>= a a2))
(assert (< (div a b) (div a2 b)))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second operand of the division operator is a variable. 
This makes the constraints non-linear and the search for satisfying interpretations of non-linear constraints is in general not terminating (it is also undecidable in general).

Comment: The example looks simple. Is there a fragment (for which a decision procedure is implemented in Z3) that captures this example?